# mask-image without fixed aspect ratio?

Tags: css, mask

is there a way to use mask-image without a fixed aspect ratio?

I'm hoping to have a mask that fills the parent (width:100% height:100%) but it seems not to be possible?

Comment: Are you using an SVG as a mask?

Comment: Yes, I am. The result seems to be the same regardless.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68508514/12571484

Comment: of course, facepalm. Thank you!